# What is the equivalent class of $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let  $F$ collection of all finite sets, Define $\approx$ on $F$ by $$X\approx Y \iff \exists f:X\to Y\quad\text{s.t. }f\text{ is a bijection}$$

What is the equivalent class of $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ for distinct $a_1,...,a_n$?

First of all $\approx$ is an equivalence relation on $F$, since I don't know the answer, I've tried to plug some sets and see how it goes $$[A]=\{X\mid  \exists f:A\to X\}$$
Hence $$[\{1,2\}]=\{X\mid  \exists f:\{1,2\}\to X\}$$

Then $\{1,2\}\in [\{1,2\}]$ and $\{2,4\},\{0.5,1\},...$ so basicaly there is an infinte number of sets just by using the function $f(x)=nx$ where $n\in \mathbb R$, so is that the general answer ?$$[\{a_1,...,a_n\}]=\{k\in \mathbb R\mid \{ka_1,...,ka_n\}\}$$

Comment: Yes, it would consist of all sets of the same size.

Comment: Not necessarily a common factor $k$... $\{ 1,2 \}$ and $\{ 2,3 \}$ are bijectable.

Comment: In a nutshell we can biject finite sets iff they have the same number of elements. Thus, we have the equiv class of singleton, that of pairs, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

$a_1, \ldots, a_n$ do not need to be numbers; they just need to be distinct objects. So your analysis leading to $[\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}] = \{k \in \Bbb R : \{ka_1, \ldots, ka_n\}\}$ cannot make sense in general.

Instead, think about what $X \approx \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ means. It means there is a bijection between $X$ and $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ i.e. $X$ has the **same cardinality** as $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ and obviously the cardinality of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ is $n$.

So $[\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}]$ is the just the collection of all finite sets of size $n$.